# Eternal storage pattern with structs

Tags: design-patterns, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm working on an up-gradable smart contracts design and I found the eternal storage pattern would be very useful (separate logic and data in key value pairs), however, it seems to fit if the value is an elementary type (uint, bytes, address, bool..), but when it comes to complex types such as structs, does it make sense to store and access each field separately?

Comment: Depends... you could look into [json](https://json.org) (or xml) if your data differs a lot, or [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) if you have always the same tabular data. Without sample data and what you want to do with it, this question is hard to answer. Probably too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is: "but when it comes to complex types such as structs, does it make sense to store and access each field separately?"

Then the answer is that is not a matter of sense, is the only way. Eternal storage provides you a way to store each and every possible data that you are using now, and you will be using in the future. In order to do that it gives you a 256bits mapping for each data type.

If the question is how will you emulate a struct in eternal storage I will give you my 2 cents:

Let's say you want to translate the following code:

```
struct thing{
    uint a;
}
mapping(byte32 => thing) things;
insertThing(byte32 index, uint v) ... {
    things[index].a = v;
}
getThingValue(byte32 thingIndex){
    return things[thingIndex].a;
}
```

into a code that uses eternal storage. My 2 cents are the following:

```
[...]
EternalStorage s;
insertThing(byte32 index, uint v){
    s.setUint(keccak256("things", index, "a"), v);
}
getThingValue(byte32 index) returns (uint){ 
    return s.getUint(keccak256("things", index, "a"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this beautiful illustration @Fernando, I'm aware of how it works, what if my struct thing contains two fields (uint a, address b), my question is do we have to send two transactions to EternalStorage s in order to store my thing instance, and access twice to s in order to retrieve it (what if my struct contains 10 fields, 10 transactions to store each)? Is there an efficient way to workaround this case?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is the price you pay for having a 100% generic storage. Any workaround would be at a cost of genericity. But I would love to know if someone has developed a workaround.